# See if a cell contains a string not from a list of strings in another column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets I have two columns, A and B, and want to know when a cell in column A contains a word that **is not** in column B.

**Column A** contains cells with multiple words per cell, comma separated:

`sarah, john, esther
sarah, john
yara, sarah`

**Column B** contains one word per cell like:

`sarah
john
esther`

I want to know when a word in the first column **is not** in the second column.  In our example, that would be *`yara`*.

Ideally that cell would go red, or another cell in the same row would show a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by applying to range A1:A the conditional formatting with custom formula

```
=counta(unique(transpose(split(A1&", "&JOIN(", ",B$1:B),", "))))>counta(unique(B$1:B))
```

Explanation.

- To the right of the inequality sign, `counta(unique(B$1:B))` counts the number of distinct words in column B.
- On the left, `A1&", "&JOIN(", ",B$1:B)` concatenates A1 with the content of column B, comma-and-space separated.
- Then `split(...,", ")` separates all of this into a row of words
- Then `counta(unique(transpose(...)))` counts the number of distinct words among these.
- Formatting is applied if the second count is greater than the first.